# rbenv not including system ruby (1.8.7) in list of available ruby versions

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, debian, rbenv, ubuntu-12.04

I'm working with Ruby on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 Desktop, but am having a problem with rbenv - it can only see versions of ruby installed by rbenv, it can't see Ubuntu's system ruby installed via Aptitude:

```
$> rbenv versions
  1.9.2-p290
* 1.9.3-p0 (set by /home/kurtosis/bin/ruby/rbenv/version)
  jruby-1.6.5.1
```

`1.8.7.352-2ubuntu1` should appear in that list as well.  Setting local or global ruby to system and then trying to run `ruby` or `irb` results in a hung prompt:

```
$> rbenv versions
  1.9.2-p290
* 1.9.3-p0 (set by /home/kurtosis/bin/ruby/rbenv/version)
  jruby-1.6.5.1
$> ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
$> rbenv global system
$> rbenv versions
  1.9.2-p290
  1.9.3-p0
  jruby-1.6.5.1
$> ruby --version
^C
$> rbenv system
rbenv: no such command `system'
$>
```

Did I miss something during installation, do you have manually add the system ruby to rbenv or something?

Ruby 1.8.7 installed via Aptitude:

```
$> aptitude show ruby
Package: ruby                            
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 4.8
Priority: optional
Section: interpreters
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 36.9 k
Depends: ruby1.8 (> 1.8.7.334-1)
Suggests: ri, ruby-dev
Conflicts: irb, irb, rdoc, rdoc
Replaces: irb, irb, rdoc, rdoc
Provides: irb, rdoc
Provided by: ruby1.8
Description: Transitional package for ruby1.8
 This is a transitional package which ensures that users of ruby will use ruby1.8 in the future. It can safely be removed.
Homepage: http://www.ruby-lang.org/


$> aptitude show ruby1.8
Package: ruby1.8                         
New: yes
State: installed
Automatically installed: yes
Version: 1.8.7.352-2ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: interpreters
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 370 k
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5), libruby1.8 (= 1.8.7.352-2ubuntu1)
Suggests: ruby1.8-examples, ri1.8
Conflicts: irb1.8 (< 1.8.7.249-3~), irb1.8 (< 1.8.7.249-3~), rdoc1.8 (< 1.8.7.249-3~), rdoc1.8 (< 1.8.7.249-3~), ri (<= 4.5), ri (<= 4.5), ri1.8 (<
           1.8.7.334-4~), ri1.8 (< 1.8.7.334-4~), ruby (<= 4.5), ruby (<= 4.5), ruby1.8
Replaces: irb1.8, irb1.8, rdoc1.8, rdoc1.8
Provides: irb1.8, rdoc1.8, ruby, ruby-interpreter
Description: Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby 1.8
 Ruby is the interpreted scripting language for quick and easy object-oriented programming.  It has many features to process text files and to do
 system management tasks (as in perl).  It is simple, straight-forward, and extensible. 

 This package provides version 1.8 series of Ruby. 

 On Debian, Ruby 1.8 is provided as separate packages.  You can get full Ruby 1.8 distribution by installing following packages. 

  ruby1.8 ruby1.8-dev ri1.8 ruby1.8-examples libtcltk-ruby1.8
Homepage: http://www.ruby-lang.org/

kurtosis@kurtosis-dm1-4050us:~/bin/projects/blogs/posterous/export$
```

PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/kurtosis/bin/ruby/rbenv/shims:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/kurtosis/bin:/opt/apache/ant/default/bin:/opt/apache/maven/default/bin:/home/kurtosis/bin/ide/eclipse:/home/kurtosis/bin/ide/idea/default/bin:/opt/scala/bin/default/bin:/opt/typesafe-stack/bin:/home/kurtosis/bin/google/android/sdk/tools:/home/kurtosis/bin/google/android/sdk/platform-tools:/home/kurtosis/bin/google/android/ndk/default/:/opt/haskell/ghc/default/bin:/opt/haskell/platform/default/bin:/home/kurtosis/bin/ruby/rbenv/bin:/home/kurtosis/bin/node/node_modules/less/bin:/home/kurtosis/bin/google/go/bin:/home/kurtosis/bin/utilities/torrent/vuze:/home/kurtosis/bin/utilities/torrent/anomos:/home/kurtosis/bin/scripts:.
```

For what it's worth, I testing with a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 Server x64 in a virtual machine.  Installed ruby via `aptitude install`ruby-full`, then downloaded and installed rbenv.  Same problem, it still can't see the system ruby for some reason.  The new PATH is:

```
/home/kurtosis/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/kurtosis/.rbenv/bin:.
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you get when you do

```
rbenv global system
ruby -v
```

or

```
rbenv local system
ruby -v
```

The special version name system tells rbenv to use the system Ruby (detected by searching your $PATH).

Refer section 3.1 at

```
https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv
```

Comment: I get the same when I try `rbenv shell` as well.  Only `rbenv global` and `rbenv local` seem to work.

Comment: Try `rbenv global system` or `rbenv local system` also please.

Comment: Ok, added that to my question text.  TLDR - both appear to work, no error when running the command, and `rbenv local system` even correctly writes .rbenv_version to the current dir with 'system' in it.  But when I then try to run `ruby --version` or `irb`, the prompt just hangs, and I have to cancel it with CTRL-c.

Comment: The `$PATH`s may be conflicting. Can you test that?

Comment: Sure, but not sure how.  The system ruby is in /usr/bin as it should be, which is in $PATH.  And the only ruby-related lines in PATH are `/home/kurtosis/bin/ruby/rbenv/shims: ... /home/kurtosis/bin/ruby/rbenv/bin:`.  Not sure whether that causes a conflict or not?  Added the full `echo $PATH` to end of my question.

Comment: @Kurtosis Sorry, can't figure it out any further. May be you should install the system ruby through rbenv too.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#readme). chruby does not automatically switch to other Rubies when starting the shell or changing to a directory. By default chruby uses the system Ruby.

```
$ chruby jruby
$ chruby
   ruby-1.9.3-p327
 * jruby-1.7.0
   rubinius-2.0.0-rc1
$ which ruby
/usr/local/jruby-1.7.0/bin/ruby
$ chruby system
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```